# TypeError: get_updates() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: typeerror, google-colaboratory

I am getting this error in the Week 3 assignment 'Fine-tuning InceptionV3 for flowers classification' in 'Google Colab'.

> Error:  TypeError: get_updates() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

This happens at the Training step, after compiling.
[# fine tune for 2 epochs (full passes through all training data)]

I can't really find a bug in the code. The previous sections have run without errors.
Could it be a version issue? Can someone please suggest the snippet from the compilation step? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TensorFlow version 2.* then just try degrading it to version 1.* by using the command:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.*
```